# How to better control the output location of files produced by rollup

Tags: rollupjs

I have the following source directory structure:

```
 -- browser/
       client.html
       client.js
```

When I run rollup it produces:

```
 -- dist/
       browser/
          client.html
       assets/
          client-7878f.js
```

I'd like it to output:

```
 -- dist/
       client.html
       assets/
          client-7878f.js
```

How would one achieve that?

My rollup options are:

```js
{
   input: 'browser/client.html',
},
```

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem today and I've been pouring over the Rollup plugin docs looking for an answer.